# How can I remove text from start to some particular selected word in bash?

Tags: regex, linux, bash, shell, sed

I have a `file1.txt` with the below contents:

`time="2016-04-25T17:43:11Z" level=info msg="SHA1 Fingerprint=9F:AD:D4:FD:22:24:20:A2:1E:0C:7F:D0:19:C5:80:42:66:56:AC:6F"`

I want the file to look as below:
`9F:AD:D4:FD:22:24:20:A2:1E:0C:7F:D0:19:C5:80:42:66:56:AC:6F`

I am using `sed` as below to remove text from start of the file to the selected word("Fingerprint") in bash.
`sed 's/^.*Fingerprint=://'`

It doesn't seem to work, so please suggest the correct command to use.
It may or may not be sed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a look-behind to match up to next double quotes:

```
$ grep -Po '(?<=Fingerprint=)[^"]*' file
9F:AD:D4:FD:22:24:20:A2:1E:0C:7F:D0:19:C5:80:42:66:56:AC:6F
```

By the way, your `sed` command is fine, you just need to remove the extra `:` at the end of the pattern:

```
$ sed 's/^.*Fingerprint=//' file
9F:AD:D4:FD:22:24:20:A2:1E:0C:7F:D0:19:C5:80:42:66:56:AC:6F"
```

This will keep the quotes. To get rid of them, match up to a double quote:

```
$ sed 's/^.*Fingerprint=\([^"]*\)"$/\1/' file
9F:AD:D4:FD:22:24:20:A2:1E:0C:7F:D0:19:C5:80:42:66:56:AC:6F
```

Comment: I am trying to use `sed 's/^.*Fingerprint=//' ` but how to make sure that I don't get the quotes in the end.

Comment: The output should be `9F:AD:D4:FD:22:24:20:A2:1E:0C:7F:D0:19:C5:80:42:66:56:AC:6F `

Comment: I am trying to escape `"` as `grep -Po '(?<=Fingerprint=)[^'\"']*' ` Please let me know if I am doing it right

Comment: @meallhour then use `sed 's/^.*Fingerprint=\([^"]*\)"$/\1/'` as described in my update. Regarding the grep approach, it is already fine in my answer, see how it does not print the double quotes.

Comment: @mealhour Feel free to check all answers.

Comment: @fedorqui I need to pass the command as a string. That is why the bash command needs to be encapsulated in a string with double quotes.  However, when i include `" grep -Po '(?<=Fingerprint=)[^"]*' " ` I don't get the desired output. It seems that i need to escape the double quotes correctly.

Comment: @meallhour passing the command as a string seems a bit weird, dangerous and prone to errors. You probably need to escape things. However, it would be best if you updated your question with relevant details so we can understand the full picture and suggest accordingly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To extract the `Fingerprint` value :

```
sed 's/.*Fingerprint=\([^"]*\)".*/\1/' file1.txt
```

Output :

```
9F:AD:D4:FD:22:24:20:A2:1E:0C:7F:D0:19:C5:80:42:66:56:AC:6F
```

All characters after `Fingerprint=` and before the quote are captured and output.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the characters in your grep:

```
grep -Eo "([0-9A-F]{2}:){19}[0-9A-F]{2}" file1.txt
```